# Empty Plot Wolfram Mathematica 13.1

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to plot a function in Wolfram Mathematica :

```
sol1 = m*x''[t] + k*x[t] + \[Beta]*x'[t] == f*Sin[\[Omega]*t + \[Phi]]

anfang1 = x'[0] == d

anfang2 = x[0] == 0

solution1 = DSolve[{sol1, anfang1, anfang2}, x[t], t]

Manipulate[
 Plot[x[t] /. solution1[[1]] /. {k -> kk, 
    m -> mm, \[Beta] -> \[Beta]\[Beta], d -> dd, 
    f -> ff, \[Omega] -> \[Omega]\[Omega], \[Phi] -> \[Phi]\[Phi] }, \
{t, 0, 10}], {dd, 0, 10}, {\[Beta]\[Beta], 0.1, 5}, {mm, 0.1, 
  10}, {kk, 0.1, 150}, {f, 0, 10}, {\[Omega], 0, 10}, {\[Phi], 0, 10}]
```

But the result is empty plot regardless of parameters

Comment: Change `{f,0,10},{\[Omega],0,10},{\[Phi],0,10}` to `{ff,0,10},{\[Omega]\[Omega],0,10}, {\[Phi]\[Phi],0,10}`